# Cannot add Class to Android Manifest Aplications

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to add my Global class to the Applications in my android manifest, but it just says 'blabla.Global' is not to 'android.app.Application' and have no idea why. Global is:

```
package com.example.bernardo.trabajo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class Global extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int contador= 0;

    public int getContador() {
    return contador;
}

public void setContador(int contador){
    contador = contador + 1;
}

private String[] theArray;

public String[] getheArray() {
    return theArray;
}

public void settheArray(String[] theArray) {
    this.theArray = theArray;
}
}
```

But it rejects it. Don't know if I missed including something or what, kinda rusty on this.

Comment: Do you want your class to just store data without Activity view? then don't extend it with AppCompatActivity. When you want an Activity view only then you extend Activity class and then also provide `onCreate` method.

Comment: as @justarandomguy has asked, please copy and paste the manifest file into your question.

Comment: This happens because your Global class extends `AppCompatActivity`. You should extend `Application` class.